# Mocha: comparing two objects, exclude fields like createdAt

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Trying to unit-test a static method that returns an instance of an object with the given arguments. I'd like to only test for the properties passed into this method because the object has auto populated fields like `createdAt` that I'd like to exclude.

Do I have to test against individual properties in this case using something like `expect().to.have.property()`, or is there a one-line solution?

http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property

Comment: One of the possible solutions is to get the list of all `expected` object fields, and remove from `actual` object all fields, expect `expectedFields`. After that assert them.

Comment: @alexmac Sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a node.js module exactly for such task: *validate only those fields that are provided in expected object*.

In example below I want to compare two objects: `actual` (it was returned by test) and `expected` (expected result). Some of the fields in `actual` are auto generated, (`_id`), so I need check only that they are exist and have a special format. Some of the fields I don't want to compare (phone with type `work`, `account.number`). So `expected` object contains only fields required for test:

```
// Some test method returns this object
let actual = {
  _id: '5945bf36ccb3fa0011e8533c',
  name: 'John',
  email: 'john@mail.com',
  phones: [
    { type: 'mobile', number: '1234567' }
    { type: 'work', number: '567382' }
  ],
  account: {
    number: '11111',
    registered: '2010-04-21'
  },
  createdAt: '2017-02-03'
};

// Ned to do the following assertions:
//   _id is exists
//   name and email match
//   mobile phone is exists and it's a number
//   account registered match
let expected = {
  _id: '_mock_',
  name: 'John',
  email: 'john@mail.com',
  phones: [
    { type: 'mobile', number: /^d{1,10}$/ }
  ],
  account: {
    registered: '2010-04-21'
  }
}

nassert.assert(actual, expected); // should pass
```

The link: [n-assert](https://github.com/AlexanderMac/n-assert)